# CSS breakpoint on retina display using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I was wondering how to set the CSS media queries on retina display to make it the same as smaller laptop screens.

It currently looks like this on my mac with 1920 x 1080 screen

[image]

I would like it to be this way just like on a smaller screen

[image]

Current media queries are:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 767.9px)
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
@media screen and (min-width: 960px)
@media screen and (min-width: 992px)
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px)
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px)
@media screen and (min-width: 1660px)
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px)
```

Hope anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For including high-res graphics, but only for screens that can make use of them. For retina you can use -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio.

```css
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

Or other highish-res:

```css
/* 1.25 dpr */
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), 
(min-resolution: 120dpi){ 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}

/* 1.3 dpr */
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3), 
(min-resolution: 124.8dpi){ 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}

/* 1.5 dpr */
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), 
(min-resolution: 144dpi){ 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```